# Random-access archive for Unix use

Tags: linux, file, archive

I'm looking for a good format for archiving entire file-systems of old Linux computers.

**TAR.GZ**
The tar.gz format is great for archiving files with UNIX-style attributes, but since the compression is applied across the entire archive, the design precludes random-access. Instead, if you want to access a file at the end of the archive, you have to start at the beginning and  decompress the whole file (which could be several hundred GB) up to the point where you find the entry you're looking for.

**ZIP**
Conversely, one selling point of the ZIP format is that it stores an index of the archive: filenames are stored separately with pointers to the location within the archive were to find the data. If I want to extract a file at the end, I look up the position of that file by name, seek to the location, and extract the data. However, it doesn't store file attributes such as ownership, permissions, symbolic links, etc.

***Other options?***
I've tried using [squashfs](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/), but it's not really designed for this purpose. The file format is not consistent between versions, and building the archive takes a lot of time and space.

What other options might suit this purpose better?

Comment: `zip` stores *nix permissions just fine here. In fact, you have to pass an argument in order to explicitly disable storing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `duplicty`. It allow you to make compressed and encrypted backup and allows random access to file. Here you can find more info about these project: http://duplicity.nongnu.org/new_format.html.

If you want use it you can also check script `duply`. Is is shell front end for `duplicty`. More info: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftplicity/

Answer (score 1):

zip (you can use http://www.info-zip.org/ ) stores file attributes - please see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29)

> Each entry is introduced by a local
>   header with information about the file
>   such as the comment, file size and
>   file name, followed by optional
>   "Extra"  data fields, and then the
>   possibly compressed, possibly
>   encrypted file data. The "Extra" data
>   fields are the key to the
>   extensibility of the ZIP format.
>   "Extra" fields are exploited to
>   support the ZIP64 format,
>   WinZip-compatible AES encryption, file
>   attributes, and higher-resolution NTFS
>   or Unix file timestamps. Other
>   extensions are possible via the
>   "Extra" field. ZIP tools are required
>   by the specification to ignore Extra
>   fields they do not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

### **File level archive format with support for random access**

**DAR** (Disk ARchive) is an archive format designed for random access. Compression is done per-file. It is not filesystem specific, but supports many fs-specific features such as xattrs, sparse files, etc. I use it as a replacement for tar. It's written in C++ and pretty portable. Downsides: The docs are hard to navigate, and the command output is very verbose.

http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/presentation.html

http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/Features.html

### **FS level archive formats**

**FSArchiver** From the website:

> 'FSArchiver is a system tool that allows you to save the contents of a
> file-system to a compressed archive file. The file-system can be
> restored on a partition which has a different size and it can be
> restored on a different file-system. Unlike tar/dar, FSArchiver also
> creates the file-system when it extracts the data to partitions.
> Everything is checksummed in the archive in order to protect the data.
> If the archive is corrupt, you just loose the current file, not the
> whole archive.'

https://www.fsarchiver.org/

**FS Spefic tools** Some filesystems come with their own utilities to dump data, such as `xfsdump` for the `xfs` filesystem.

### **Disk cloning software**

**FileZilla** is a disk cloning software, but the way it clones filesystems is pretty smart. It will prefer a fs-specific dump rather than a block-level copy where possible. You can clone a disk with CloneZilla and restore it to a smaller disk, or restore only specfic filesystem within the disk backup.

The backup is arranged in a directory structure that has output from several different backup tools and some coordinating metadata. It's easy to manipulate it with separate utilities.

https://filezilla-project.org/

### **When not to use these tools**

Backing up entire old systems is a good use for the tools above. But if you're using a modern linux system, where most software comes from a repo, it's easy to regenerate system level data by doing a new install, or using configuration management.

Personally I've changed my approach to only back up user and configuration data for systems that can easily be reinstalled.

On linux computers I manage, I set up hourly snapshots of ~/Projects with snapper on btrfs, and do long-term backup to  rsync.net using borgbackup. System setup scripts are in Ansible (or some other IaC tool), and dotfiles are stored with a sparse git repo.

Thanks to this approach, it's now much more economical to store backups in cloud storage services.